# Change the direction of Hebrew Character during PDF creation by laravel DomPdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.4, dompdf, hebrew

I have a serious problem,

I want to show the Hebrew words in RTL format after PDF creation, but it's not showing. It always shows LTR.

I have some words combinations of English and Hebrew language.

I did some search on google but no luck.

I am using [Laravel DomPdf.](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

I have checked my dompdf core file `DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED` and  its value is `"DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED" => true,`  still not abel to get the solution.

Here is my blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">

    </head>
    <body>

    <table class="lead" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'firefly, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif'; ">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Date</th>
               <th width="15%" style="font-weight: bold;">Name</th>
               <th width="20%" style="font-weight: bold;">Details</th>
               <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Contact Origin</th>
               <th width="15%" style="font-weight: bold;">Status</th>
               <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Comment</th>
               <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Country</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <?php
            foreach($leadInfo as $k=>$v){ 

            $continent = getAllContinentName($v->country);
            if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Asia")){
              $backGround = "#FFB300";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Africa")){
              $backGround = "#FFB300";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("North America")){
              $backGround = "#009792";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("South America")){
              $backGround = "#FF7E00";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Antarctica")){
              $backGround = "#15E6E8";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Europe")){
              $backGround = "#0074FF";
            } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Australia")){
              $backGround = "#05A900";
            } else {
              $backGround = "#FFFFFF";
            }

            if($v->email_status_id == 10){
              $statusBackGround = "#a9d18d";
            } else if($v->email_status_id == 11){
              $statusBackGround = "#ff0000";
            } else if($v->email_status_id == 12){
              $statusBackGround = "#b3c6e7";
            } else if($v->email_status_id == 13){
              $statusBackGround = "#c09200";
            } else if($v->email_status_id == 14){
              $statusBackGround = "#ffff00";
            } else {
              $statusBackGround = "#FFFFFF";
            }

         ?>
            <tr>
               <td> {{ date('m-d-Y',strtotime($v->created_date)) }} </td>
               <td>{{ $v->name }}</td>
               <td>{{ mb_substr($v->message, 0, 300) }}</td> <!-- This line has combination of english and hebrew language-->
               <td>{{ $v->contact_origin }}</td>
               <td style="direction: rtl !important; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; color:black; background-color: {{ $statusBackGround }};">{{ $v->status_name }}</td> <!-- This line has only hebrew language -->
               <td>{{ $v->comment }}</td>
               <td style="color:black; background-color: {{ $backGround }}" >{{ getAllCountryName($v->country) }}</td>
            </tr>
         <?php  }  ?>
         </tbody>
      </table>   

    </body>
    </html>
```

It would be great if anyone helps me to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf (up to and including 0.8.1) does not currently support RTL text ([see issue 1009](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1009)). There is a [work around](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/712#issuecomment-120714740), but the results are passable at best.

If you're interested in trying it out modify the Text rendered by adding the following code at [line 83](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.8.1/src/Renderer/Text.php#L84):

```
if (strtolower($style->direction) === 'rtl') {
  preg_match_all('/./us', $text, $ar);
  $text = join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
  // if there are numbers in the string so the next line reverse the number back treat also numbers with dot (decimal) and email
  $text = preg_replace_callback('/\d+-\d+|\d+|\d+\.\d+|\S+@\S+/', function (array $m) { return strrev($m[0]); }, $text);
}
```

Comment: I have gone through those links before I came here to ask this question. And I have seen your comments on GitHub issues, Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it out. But for now, I used TCPDF, which is working fine for me.

Comment: That's a more viable option until Dompdf has native support. Also wkhtmltopdf should work well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package which supports rtl languages such as persian and arabic

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

in order to change the direction , just within the html tag which is going to be converted to pdf , use dir="rtl"